# Raspberry Pi - Rainforest EMU-2 - Python - Read time from SCE smart meter

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, raspberry-pi, epoch

I am now to programming in Python and this is my first project.  Any help would be appreciated.

I recently obtained a device from Rainforest that reads my electric meter.  The unit has a USB port accessible via USB.   I managed to hook the device up to my Raspberry Pi and extract a hex string from the serial port.  Currently the string is reading 0x18f0cb39.  I need to take this number and convert it into proper format and output it as time and date.  The manual for device I am programming is at http://www.rainforestautomation.com/sites/default/files/download/rfa-z106/raven_xml_api_r127.pdf

I am quite confused when it comes to converting epoch to time and date.  I put #'s in front of lines having difficulties.

The code that I have written is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial
import time
serial.port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, timeout=0.5)
serial.port.write("<Command><Name>get_time</Name><Refresh>N</Refresh></Command>")
response=serialport.readline(none)
response=serialport.readline(none)
response=serialport.readline(none)
response=serialport.readline(none)
response=serialport.readline(none)
myString=response[13:23]
#struct_time = int(raw_input(((myString >> 40) +1970, (ts >> 32 & 0xFF) +1, ts >> 24 & 0xFF, ts>> 16)))
#thetime=time.strftime("%7-%m-%d-%H-%M-%s)
print myString
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I don't understand exactly how you are using the slice 13:23 to get your time (in hex) out of the TimeCluster response, but the gist of your question and your commented out code seems to be how do I convert 0x18f0cb39 to a local date and time?

```
>>> import time
>>> help(time)
(output snipped, but this is so handy....)
>>> t = 0x18f0cb39
>>> time.ctime(t)
'Tue Apr  5 15:37:29 1983'
>>> time.localtime(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1983, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=15, tm_min=37, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=95, tm_isdst=0)
```

Since you posted your question 6 days ago and today is the 11th, the date in that answer seems to be off by exactly 30 years, so I must be doing something wrong, but maybe this will take you a step in the right direction or prompt someone else to write a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rainforest RAVEn XML API docs, the TimeCluster response to your GetTime request says this about the data format:

```
TimeCluster notifications provide the current time reported on the 
meter in both UTC and Local time. The time values are the number of 
seconds since 1-Jan-2000 UTC.
```

As you've guessed, the Python time is seconds since 1-Jan-1970.  So you can convert from the Rainforest epoch of 1-Jan-2000 to the Python epoch like this:

```
myString=response[13:23] 
seconds_since_2000 = int(myString, 16)
# compute number of seconds between 1-Jan-1970 and 1-Jan-2000
delta = calendar.timegm(time.strptime("2000-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"))
time.ctime(seconds_since_2000 + delta)
```

(Note: the above is written for example only.  In a production system, you'd probably want to write a dedicated function to convert between the raw hex text produced by the RAVEn and a python time object.)